# Proper way to extend in java while changing variables

Tags: java, class, variables, extend

I am making simulations in java but i am having a hard time manipulating variables while extending.

To make the problem easier to express let's consider 2 Java classes Grid1 and Grid2.

Grid1

```
Class Grid1 {
    public int a;
    public int grid[];

    public Grid1(int a) {
       this.a=a;
       grid = new int[50];
    }
    
    public update() {
       for (int i : grid) {
           i+=a;
       }
    }
}
```

Grid2

```
Class Grid2 extend Grid1 {

    public Grid2(int a) {
       super(a)
    }
    
    @Override
    public update() {
       for (int i : grid) {
           i+=2*a;
       }
    }
}
```

Now let say i want to use Grid1 and Grid2 in the simulations. So i create two classes Sim1 and Sim2.

Sim1

```
Class Sim1 {
    public Grid1 grid1;

    public Sim1() {
       grid1 = new Grid1(10);
    }
    
    public draw() {
       draw_list(grid1); //lets say draw list is defined elsewhere
    }
}
```

Sim2

```
Class Sim2 extend Sim1{
    public Grid2 grid2;

    public Sim2() {
       grid2 = new Grid2(10);
    }
}
```

Now when i run `update()` in my main on Sim2 then draw_list i get the picture of Grid1 and not Grid2...
So how can i fix this ?
In other words i want to extend a class and change the type of the variable in the new extended class.

Thank you

PS: Actually the simulation are about conway game of life and the immigration automata. I want to extend immigration to be like conway ...

Comment: I think your code has more problems than this, but to answer narrowly I think the first thing I would consider is to move `draw_list()` to the `Grid` class and let it handle its own variables.

Comment: But isn't it better to separate "Calculations" and "graphical" function ?

Comment: You still need to meet your functional requirements.  If a model class needs to provide data to another class, you should provide a convenient format for doing so.  Having your graphical class reach inside and pull out internal variables breaks encapsulation, which is always going to be a bigger deal than separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dogs are animals, right? Well, all Grid2 instances are also Grid1s. For the same reason: `Grid2 extends Grid1` means: Grid2 is everything Grid1 defines, *and more*.

Thus, if you extend `Sim1` you do **not** want to add a second field, because now your Sim2 has 2 fields. Instead, you want to end up assigning an instance of Grid2 to the field which is type Grid1. End up running `Grid1 g = new Grid2();` which is perfectly legal java code, for the same reason `Animal a = new Dog();` would be fine.

As written, your `Grid1` class is dead in the water. You MUST call one of your parent class's constructors, and your Sim1 constructor makes a new Grid1 instance. Which you don't want when Grid2's constructor runs. We need to fix that, too. You've also slattered `public` all over this, that's not very nice.

```
class Sim1 {
  private Grid1 grid;

  public Sim1() {
    this(new Grid1(10));
  }

  protected Sim1(Grid1 grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
  }
  
  public draw() {
     draw_list(grid); //lets say draw list is defined elsewhere
  }
}
```

```
Class Sim2 extend Sim1 {
  public Sim2() {
    super(new Grid2(10));
  }
}
```

We now have 2 constructors; `Sim2` can choose which one it wants to invoke, and we obviously invoke the one where we provide the ready-made Grid instance.